# Layover in Sharjah requires transit visa for indian citizens?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I have a flight from Delhi to Yerevan via Sharjah (layover of approx 4-5 hrs), will i be needing a transit visa or can travel without it?

Answer (score 2):

According to IATA Timatic, the database used by airlines, you can transit without a visa:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Read it in full [here](https://www.emirates.com/ae/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=AM&DV=Armenia&TC=AE&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=24458a20192c16527751f0913b26427df67cc560)

Answer (score 0):

According to Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

This means you can transit without a visa if you stay in the international transit area.

This means:

- you can’t pass through immigration
- you can’t exit the airport
- you can’t recheck your luggage